# Does using getters improve performance?

Tags: javascript

In [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fswm1n) example i have 2 array, one using getters, and one without.

In memory chrome snapshot i found that the size of object with getters is 224 b, and without getters is 125,336 b.
but the size of the list of two of them are equals (8,000,016 b).
how  can it be?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The object with getters does t hold the json as value but generates it in the fly ... so of course much less memory is needed. The array just holds references to the objects, so both arrays have the same size. Still the object without getter should perform better because its values are „cached“ . Memory consumption does t directly relate to performance.

Comment: ok, thanks. so, using getters does  improve when i have large  data, and using getters only for part of them, like virtual scroll table.

Comment: Sounds like a premature micro-optimisation. Does it cause problems currently? Have you profiled this?

Comment: @yantrap : no - memory consumtion. For example i would not use setter and getters for games because there is the overhead of calling a function and calculating the value for each attribute call

Answer (score 1):

Personally, this was interesting to look at

**without getters**

As per your code, you are repeating `JSON.stringify` for 1000 times then storing it in an object while just creating an instance for the class. Even if you don't use the `json` object the memory for 1000 `this` contexts are already occupied. This memory space will remain occupied and the object will sit there until javascript starts the garbage collection process

When you click `without getters`repeatedly,  the memory will keep getting added and that is why you have the huge memory for `userWithoutGetters`.

```
class userWithoutGeters{
    ...
    ...
    json = JSON.stringify(this).repeat(1000);
}
```

**with getters**

As per your code, you repeat `JSON.stringify` 1000 times only while invoking the get method and the code logic isn't storing the returned value anywhere. Value is simply returned, no reference is stored in the heap no matter how many times you hit `with getters`. Less memory is consumed in this case.

To check the increase in memory,

- First do a page refresh and take snapshot
- Then click on `without getters` & `with getters`  button any number of times as you wish
- Take snapshot again to see the increase in memory usage.

Suggest you to follow object oriented principles where ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

> how can it be [that the arrays have the same size] ?

Because the arrays only contain references to the objects. These references always have the same size, the objects can be found in another part of the memory dump.

> Does using getters improve performance?

Does that matter? Using a getter serves a different purpose than storing a property directly, choose the one that makes sense.